# evaluation version of monotouch failing to build to native code

Tags: xamarin.ios

this is Ajit.
I tried downloading the trial version of monotouch from the website but all the links were broken.
So I downloaded the following by digging from google.
(*)MonoDevelop-3.0.3.5
(*)MonoFramework-MRE-2.10.9_11.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg
(*)Monotouch-eval-5.1.0.pkg

but after doing so when I run a sample ios app from the xamarin website only then it fails to build -> not being able to compile to native code.
This is error log.

---

Building Solution: HelloWorld_iPhone (Debug|iPhoneSimulator)

Building: HelloWorld_iPhone (Debug|iPhoneSimulator)
Performing main compilation...
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs /noconfig "/out:/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloWorld_iPhone.exe" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" /nologo /warn:4 /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 "/define:DEBUG"  /t:exe "/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/Main.cs" "/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/AppDelegate.cs" "/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhoneViewController.cs" "/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhoneViewController.designer.cs"

Copying content files
Copying '/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/Images/Icons/57_icon.png' to '/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloWorld_iPhone.app/57_icon.png'
Copying '/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/Images/Icons/114_icon.png' to '/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloWorld_iPhone.app/114_icon.png'
Copying '/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/Images/Icons/72_icon.png' to '/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloWorld_iPhone.app/72_icon.png'
Copying '/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/Images/Icons/29_icon.png' to '/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloWorld_iPhone.app/29_icon.png'
Copying '/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/Images/Icons/58_icon.png' to '/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloWorld_iPhone.app/58_icon.png'
Copying '/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/Images/Icons/50_icon.png' to '/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloWorld_iPhone.app/50_icon.png'
Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings

Compiling to native code
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -v --nomanifest --nosign -sim "/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloWorld_iPhone.app" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -debug -nolink -sdk "5.1" "/Users/PBSK/Desktop/HelloWorld_iPhone/HelloWorld_iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HelloWorld_iPhone.exe"
This feature is not supported in the evaluation version
No gcc compiler found!
mtouch exited with code 1

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 0 warnings

---

Xcode version is 4.4 and Mac version is 10.7.4.

-Thanks!

Comment: I'd say the line "This feature is not supported in the evaluation version" pretty much seals the fate of this question - whatever other issues there might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the manual installation for MonoTouch evaluation which FINALLY works!:

Download and install packages listed below, in the order given:

1) Mono: http://download.mono-project.com/archive/2.10.9/macos-10-x86/10/MonoFramework-MDK-2.10.9_10.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg

2) MonoDevelop: http://download.xamarin.com/monodevelop/Mac/MonoDevelop-3.0.dmg

3) Eval MonoTouch: http://download.xamarin.com/priv/d6d0ad447c01dd2bbbbbba829f6e1a/MonoTouch/Mac-eval/monotouch-eval-5.2.11.pkg

For the above mentioned environment this combination works like magic.
Just hope that they'll fix the broken links on their site too or else many other newbies would continue to get discouraged.
Thanks to support people of Xamarin who shared these links.

Answer (score 3):

> but all the links were broken

Please email support@xamarin.com if you have any issues with the website.

> Monotouch-eval-5.1.0.pkg

This is an pretty old, **beta** version of MonoTouch.

MonoTouch 5.2.12 is the *current* stable release while 5.3.5 is the current **unstable** release.

> No gcc compiler found

This means no C compiler was found. In *general* you should make sure your MonoDevelop preferences (SDK Locations) are set the point to your Xcode installation directory.

However in this case I think your MonoTouch version is too old to work with Xcode 4.4. Updating your evaluation version to 5.2.12 is the first step you should try to fix this.